# SQL - With statement in WHERE claue

Tags: sql, where-clause, with-statement

HI,

Does a WITH state can live in a WHERE clause?

for instance:

```
SELECT tbl1.name , tbl1.ID  
FROM DBTABLE0001 AS tbl1
WHERE  ( 
    exists(

        WITH H (super, ID, depth) AS 
        ( 
        SELECT ROOT.parent, ROOT.ID , 0 
        FROM DBTABLE0001 ROOT  
        WHERE ROOT.ID = tbl1.ID 

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT PARENT.parent, PARENT.ID , CHILD.depth + 1 
        FROM H CHILD, DBTABLE0001 PARENT 
        WHERE PARENT.ID = CHILD.super 

        )

        SELECT ID 
        FROM H 
        WEHER H.ID = "abcd"
        ORDER BY depth

    ) 
)
```

Thanks,
Mo.

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow. Next time please use the {} button to format your code.

Comment: Have you tried it ? (*you should change the `WEHER` to `WHERE` though*)

Comment: Did you have a particular DBMS in mind?

Comment: You use `H` recursively. I'm not sure this is allowed. Have you tried it in any RDBMS ?

Comment: 10x guys, H should be recursive, and it's allowed. pls see my response to Frazin to understand my goal.

Answer (score 4):

You should place your with statements at the begining of your query. then you can use it every where :

```
WITH H (super, ID, depth) AS           
            (SELECT ROOT.parent, ROOT.ID , 0 
                  FROM DBTABLE0001 ROOT            
              WHERE ROOT.ID = DBTABLE0001.ID             
              UNION ALL             
              SELECT PARENT.parent, PARENT.ID , CHILD.depth + 1                         FROM H CHILD, DBTABLE0001 PARENT           
                WHERE PARENT.ID = CHILD.super) 

SELECT tbl1.name , tbl1.ID    
    FROM DBTABLE0001 AS tbl1  
    WHERE  (exists(SELECT ID FROM H WEHER H.ID = "abcd"  ORDER BY depth))
```

Comment: Problem is that the WITH involved the main select FROM table: 
WHERE ROOT.ID = tbl1.ID  
the tbl1 param is the outer select table.

Comment: But then it wont run in the right context - this also what db2 is yelling: SQL0206N  "DBTABLE0001.ID" is not valid in the context where it is used

Comment: is the DBTABLE0001 a table name or not ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Frazin.
DBTABLE0001 is the table name, but ROOT is an alias to the same table. H run is running recursively on each record and bring me some results (the table represents some hierarchy content) , and my goal is to get all the records from DBTABLE0001 that its recursive execution return some results.

Comment: When you use With statement, you should plcae your with statement at the begining of your query. other solution that you may want to try is to use Cursor to create such recursion .